# line 4: 5 + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")

Tags: ubuntu

noticing the error mentioned in the subject line when trying to execute the below listed bash script on Ubuntu (53-Ubuntu  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

```
#!/bin/bash

read x y
echo $(($x + $y))
```

However same runs perfectly on Redhat and CentOS.

Please help me find why this is happening all OS's have bash version 4.3.11(1)-release

Comment: #!/bin/bash was used

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l /bin/bash` (on the failing OS).

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root 0 1021112 Oct  7 19:22 /bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives error because you provide only one input number, not two. In such case read assigns this number to variable `x`, but `y` will stay empty, so next line looks like `echo $(($x + ))`. As we know operator `+` takes two operands, but here `y` (the second one) is missing, thus the error `operand expected (error token is “+ ”)`.

Comment: BTW, you can omit `$` inside parentheses: `echo $((x+y))`

Comment: why is this behaviour noticed in Ubuntu reading variables separately resolved the issue however i am not sure why it works in RHEL and CentOS but not in ubuntu where in we have to read the variables one at a time